# How to create content sized popover in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot find a way to present a popover view that is just as big as its contents.  I'm using the following code:

```
func show_popup(_ popVC: UIViewController, sender: UIButton)
{

    let v = sender
    popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popOverVC = popVC.popoverPresentationController
    popOverVC?.delegate = self
    popOverVC?.sourceView = v
    popOverVC?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: v.bounds.midX, y: v.bounds.minY, width: 0, height: 0)
    //popVC.preferredContentSize = popVC.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    //popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 220, height: 140)
    present(popVC, animated: true)
    popup = popVC
}
```

If I explicitly set the preferredContentSize to 220x140 then the popover is displayed with that size, like this:

[Image showing explicitly set popover size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ3Tw.png)

If I set the preferredContentSize to systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize) then the popover does not set its size to the content (what is desired) but the popover is sized to the system default, like this:

[Image showing system default popover size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZKeK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found a workaround.  Since the popup only consists of a linear list of buttons I can calculate the width of the text for the widest button and then set the popup size based upon that width.